# Local Branch deleted in github

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a local branch named `mass-communication-rm` and I have pushed the code to that branch but due to some issue I deleted that branch from local and now again I created the branch with same name so if I push code to that branch so what will happen will it create a separate branch or the code will be pushed to same branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a new branch with the same name.
Just checkout to the branch:

```
git checkout mass-communication-rm
```

git is smart enough to create a local branch of `mass-communication-rm` if it only exists as remote branch. The local branch is created automatically and it will track its correspondent remote branch.

This is the safest way to get back the same branch as you deleted; AFAIK.

I understand this doesn't answer your original question as in the post, but I think this answers the root cause pushed you to write the post.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you deleted that branch from local, not remote. Now rewrite it and try to push, it will be merged to same remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

Github will try to push changes to the same branch. Whether it will or not it depends. If your new local branch has the exact same code as of online one, Githhub will allow you to push new changes. Otherwise, it will show an error saying

> Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have

**Solution: 1**

A better solution would be to delete your local branch using:

```
git branch -D mass-communication-rm
```

**Note:** It will delete all code in local branch **mass-communication-rm**

Now fetch online branch using

```
git fetch origin mass-communication-rm
```

Checkout to that branch

```
git checkout mass-communication-rm
```

Continue your work...

**Solution: 2**

Other solution could be to pull the online **mass-communication-rm** branch. It will merge the online branch into your local one and then try pushing. It will work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What matters to Git are the *commits*.

To really understand what's going on, keep these two ideas separate in your head:

- Commits have hash IDs, like `b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f`.
- Branch *names* like `master` simply store *one* commit hash ID.

The *true name* of any commit is its raw hash ID.  If *I* have commit `b7b<blah>`, and *you* have commit `b7b<blah>` (for the same <blah>), we have the same *commit*.  It does not matter what *branch name*, or names, we use for it, as long as the *ID* matches.

When you delete a branch name in your Git, that's pretty much all that happens: you have deleted the *name* `mass-communication-rm`, which your Git was using to remember some big ugly hash ID.  Let's use the letters *MCR* to stand in for the hash ID.  Since you ran a successful `git push` earlier, you sent that *commit*, the one with ID *MCR*, to another Git repository, and that other Git repository now has it.  As long as *they* still have commit *MCR*, you can always call up that Git repository and get it back.

Now, when you gave them—the Git on GitHub—commit *MCR*, you were calling it `mass-communication-rm`.  You probably told *them* to call it `mass-communication-rm`.  Remember, their Git is just like your Git: it has *its own* branch names.  Just as in your Git, each of *their* branch names remembers one big ugly hash ID.

Your Git also remembers that their Git exists and has a URL that your Git stores under the *remote name* `origin`.  Your own Git will remember *their* branch names under your own Git's `origin/*` names, which your Git calls *remote-tracking names*.  This means that *your* Git has a name, `origin/mass-communication-rm`, that remembers the hash ID of commit *MCR* ... so your Git also still has a *name* for this big ugly hash ID!

Let's review:

- Your Git remembers their Git's URL via the short name `origin` (which your Git calls a *remote*).
- You gave them—the GIt on GitHub, at that URL—commit *MCR* and told them to keep it under *their* name `mass-communication-rm`.
- So *your* Git has `origin/mass-communication-rm`, which remembers the big ugly hash ID for commit *MCR*.

If you run `git branch -r` (to list remote-tracking names), or `git branch -a` (to list both local branch names *and* remote-tracking names), you will see that your own `mass-communication-rm` is gone, but `origin/mass-communication-rm` is still there.<sup>1</sup>

This, in turn, means you can run:

```
$ git checkout mass-communication-rm
```

to *re-create* your own local `mass-communication-rm` name based on `origin/mass-communication-rm`.  That is, your Git will *create* a new local branch name, and stuff into that name, the big ugly hash ID your Git is remembering under the name `origin/mass-communication-rm`.

You can then add new commits.  Adding a new commit to a branch consists of *making* the new commit (in the usual way) and then having your own Git set *your* branch name to remember the new, unique, big-ugly-hash-ID that your Git generates *for* that new commit.  The new commit itself remembers the *previous* hash ID; your own branch name remembers the new ID, and your Git finds the *old* commit—the one we've been calling *MCR* here—by searching *backwards* from the new commit.

For much more on the above, including another role that branch names have in keeping commits "alive", see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that `git branch -r` prints `origin/mass-communication-rm`, but `git branch -a` prints `remotes/origin/mass-communication-rm`.  The *full* name is `refs/remotes/origin/mass-communication-rm`.  The full name of your own branch is `refs/heads/mass-communication-rm`.

Git normally strips off the `refs/` and the `heads/` or `remotes/` parts of these names as they're not very useful.  For some unknown reason, `git branch -a` doesn't strip off the `remotes/` part, while `git branch -r` does.